# Get program information from Libvlcsharp (dvb-t)

Tags: .net-core, libvlcsharp, dvb-t

I have a requirement to take a dvb-t feed into a system then be able to push out channels over a local network as an rtsp stream in a dot net core environment.

LibVLCSharp seems to fit the bill nicely but I'm getting caught up trying to determine the PID values for each channel so I can selectively distribute individual channels.

I've found if I play a media element I can get the EPG info out which contains the PID's and channel names from the LibVLC logs, it feels a little long handed to do this though.

I know in the VLC UI you can select individual channels from *Playback->Programs* so I feel there's something I'm missing.

Is the only way for me to get that information by parsing the logs or have I missed something?

Comment: As far as I know, the EPG feature is one of the things that are exclusive to the VLC app and is not available through libvlc, and thus not LibVLCSharp

Comment: I can get some EPG logs out of the libvlc object which is where I'm currently able to get the PID values/channel names.

Answer (score 0):

```
TS muxer (libdvbpsi) (mux_ts)
      --sout-ts-standard={dvb,atsc} 
                                 Digital TV Standard
      --sout-ts-pid-video=<integer [32 .. 8190]> 
                                 Video PID
          Assign a fixed PID to the video stream. The PCR PID will
          automatically be the video.
      --sout-ts-pid-audio=<integer [32 .. 8190]> 
                                 Audio PID
          Assign a fixed PID to the audio stream.
      --sout-ts-pid-spu=<integer [32 .. 8190]> 
                                 SPU PID
          Assign a fixed PID to the SPU.
      --sout-ts-pid-pmt=<integer [32 .. 8190]> 
                                 PMT PID
          Assign a fixed PID to the PMT
      --sout-ts-tsid=<integer>   TS ID
          Assign a fixed Transport Stream ID.
      --sout-ts-netid=<integer>  NET ID
          Assign a fixed Network ID (for SDT table)
      --sout-ts-program-pmt=<string> 
                                 PMT Program numbers
          Assign a program number to each PMT. This requires "Set PID to ID of
          ES" to be enabled.
      --sout-ts-es-id-pid, --no-sout-ts-es-id-pid 
                                 Set PID to ID of ES
                                 (default disabled)
          Sets PID to the ID if the incoming ES. This is for use with
          --ts-es-id-pid, and allows having the same PIDs in the input and
          output streams.
      --sout-ts-muxpmt=<string>  Mux PMT (requires --sout-ts-es-id-pid)
          Define the pids to add to each pmt. This requires "Set PID to ID of
          ES" to be enabled.
      --sout-ts-sdtdesc=<string> SDT Descriptors (requires --sout-ts-es-id-pid)
          Defines the descriptors of each SDT. This requires "Set PID to ID of
          ES" to be enabled.
```

Maybe this helps, never tried what you're wanting to achieve so I'm not sure. You can use any of this [options](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help) from libvlcsharp https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/blob/3.x/docs/libvlc_documentation.md#libvlc-options

Comment: yea, I've seen very little around on what I'm trying to do which makes this fun. As far as I can tell from the options they're more about applying settings than they are about getting the information I need out. I can create the stream once I have the PID fine, it's determining them in the first place that seems to be the biggest road block.

Comment: Can you share the full logs you get from using both libvlc and the VLC app with your stream please? Maybe relevant https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libdvbpsi/-/blob/master/examples/check_cc_pid.c and https://code.videolan.org/videolan/libdvbpsi/-/blob/master/examples/get_pcr_pid.c

Comment: it's not the logs that are causing me issues - I can get the values I need out from monitoring the log stream - my question was really as to whether this is the only method or whether there is a method through the libvlcsharp libraries that will provide me with the information I need without the need for log processing.

Comment: As far as I know, this is the only way through the libvlc. If I understand correctly what it does, libdvbpsi seems like a better option for that.